# Can EditText.getText() ever be null?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext

I am using `TextInputLayout` with `TextInputEditText` and Android Lint always warns me that calling `toString()` on `getText()` might produce a `NullPointerException`.

Personally, I have never had a NPE ever doing this, not even when the `TextInputEditText` was empty.

I remember reading that the return value can only be `null` upon creation of the view or something similar somewhere.

Is it production safe to simply ignore the Lint warning or should I check for `null` just in case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Editable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Editable.html) is an `interface`. It is possible that the implementations of this `interface` that you use cannot be `null`, but even if we factually knew that it is safe in your use-cases to not handle NPE, I would advise against it. There might be implementations for that interface in use that might have null as a value. You could implement an util method to solve this if the problem is that you repeat this over and over again.

EDIT

As Ryan M has pointed out in the comment section and the documentation confirms, Editable does not have a getText method, however, this does not change the general thoughts of separating our concerns.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Indeed, I have a registration form with six ``TextInputEditText``s. Can you explain what you mean by util method, please?

Comment: @RenéSpies of course. You can implement some class, let's call it Util for now and there you can implement a static method, let's call it getString, which is given an Object parameter as input and handles the NPE possibility. For example: ```return ((input == null) ? "" : input);``` and then you can use it as Util.getString(myEditable.getText()). From there on you will not have to worry about the possibility of null values and it is handled properly.

Comment: One problem with this answer...`Editable` does not have a `getText` method.

Comment: @RyanM You are right. ``EditText#getText`` returns an ``Editable`` which can be null.

Comment: @RyanM that's true, good catch. Edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

To answer this, we can look at the source code.

`TextView.getText()`, the superclass method, is [pretty straightforward](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/e3cea2b7be6fd5076eb64bfa884ab53135564bd2:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java;l=2298): it returns `mText`.

[`mText` is marked as nullable](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/e3cea2b7be6fd5076eb64bfa884ab53135564bd2:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java;l=695), but looking through the code, nothing sets it to null, and the constructor [checks it](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/e3cea2b7be6fd5076eb64bfa884ab53135564bd2:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java;l=1622;drc=e13851556bcfecff6de4b3a1a99be4dcaa5853a1) to make sure it's not `null` before returning.  It is marked `@UnsupportedAppUsage`, though, which means at least third-party code may access it via reflection.

For some additional hints if that is something that could reasonably happen, we can look at other usage within `TextView` to see if this is a valid state.  Methods like [`length()`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/e3cea2b7be6fd5076eb64bfa884ab53135564bd2:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/TextView.java;l=2307;drc=e13851556bcfecff6de4b3a1a99be4dcaa5853a1) and others call a method on `mText` without a null-check, so if it's null after the constructor returns, you're going to be seeing crashes.

However, we also need to look at `EditText`, because `EditText` [overrides `getText()`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/e3cea2b7be6fd5076eb64bfa884ab53135564bd2:frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/EditText.java;l=107;bpv=0).  There's a comment in there that gives us the hint we need:

```java
        // This can only happen during construction.
        if (text == null) {
```

The method otherwise returns the result of `super.getText()` through various means, so our analysis above applies: it can't otherwise be null.

One more place to check: does [`TextInputEditText`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/497cb97ef092243a73904d8842d93df85db7adc3/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputEditText.java) override `getText()`?  It does not.

So the short answer is: no, not unless you have a strange subclass of it, or you're calling it during construction (which would only be possible if you've subclassed it yourself).  It is technically not enforced, but it really should not happen with standard components from Google, though [CommonsWare's point below is a good thing to keep in mind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61282325/can-edittext-gettext-ever-be-null/61283012?noredirect=1#comment108424986_61283012).

Comment: Good answer, thank you and my question never assumed ``Editable`` has a ``getText()`` method.

Comment: I was referring to the title: "Can Editable.getText() ever be null?" (which I've edited to clarify, and removed from my answer now that you've confirmed this was the intent)

Comment: Sorry, I oversaw this. Thank you for editing it for me.

Comment: @RyanM: Can I offer a counterpoint? `EditText` is probably the widget most often modified by device manufacturers. And while device manufacturer testing has improved over the years, they still overlook things, and their testing is likely to focus on what the SDK contract calls for. So, "standard components from Google" is really only assured on Nexus/Pixel devices and emulators. Everywhere else... I'd recommend defensive programming. And I eagerly await Jetpack Compose and a UI framework that manufacturers can't mess with... :-)